# How to carry out arithmetic operations on dataframes in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to validate if my written code is correct or not. For that I have to use the formula:

```
(nvl(units_inflow,0)- nvl(units_inflow_can,0)-nvl(units_outflow,0)+nvl(units_outflow_can,0))*nav_value
```

This code is in Oracle SQL and I need to carry out the same operation in PySpark. As of now, just like how `nvl` is used in the above code, I have used `fill()` in Pyspark to replace null value with 0.

There are these 5 columns in my t3 dataframe namely

```
["units_inflow","units_inflow_can","units_outflow","units_outflow_can","nav_value"]
```

The code that I have written so far is:

```
t3= t3.na.fill(value=0,subset=["units_inflow","units_inflow_can","units_outflow","units_outflow_can"])
z = t3.select("units_inflow").groupby().sum().show()

y = t3.select("units_inflow_can").groupby().sum().show()

x = t3.select("units_outflow").groupby().sum().show()

w = t3.select("units_outflow_can").groupby().sum().show()

u = t3.select("nav_value").groupby().sum().collect()

print(u)
```

Although after doing all this I am unable to get the output. I think I am going wrong somewhere in the code conversion. I have done the arithmetic operations separately in my calculator by taking in consideration the sum output of each column.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle `nvl` function is the same as `coalesce`, you can simply keep the formula as it is by replacing `nvl` function :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

t3.select(
    (
        F.coalesce(F.col("units_inflow"), F.lit(0)) -
        F.coalesce(F.col("units_inflow_can"), F.lit(0)) -
        F.coalesce(F.col("units_outflow"), F.lit(0)) +
        F.coalesce(F.col("units_outflow_can"), F.lit(0))
    ) * F.col("nav_value")
).show()
```

Or by using sql expression:

```
t3.select(
    F.expr("""(
            coalesce(units_inflow, 0) - coalesce(units_inflow_can, 0) -
            coalesce(units_outflow, 0) + coalesce(units_outflow_can, 0)
           ) * nav_value
    """)
).show()
```

Comment: Yes! Your solution worked perfectly and did half of my job.... but my further goal is to find out the aggregate sum of the t4 where

t4 = t3.select(
    (
        F.coalesce(F.col("units_inflow"), F.lit(0)) -
        F.coalesce(F.col("units_inflow_can"), F.lit(0)) -
        F.coalesce(F.col("units_outflow"), F.lit(0)) +
        F.coalesce(F.col("units_outflow_can"), F.lit(0))
    ) * F.col("nav_value")
)

What I mean is if I make a column which has the final value of t3.select(entire content), I want to take sum of that entire column.

Comment: Yes yes.... what my goal is that I want to check if the sum of


`(nvl(units_inflow,0)- nvl(units_inflow_can,0)-nvl(units_outflow,0)+nvl(units_outflow_can,0))*nav_value`
and my final answer should be 87k Cr. Then I can say my previous code was correct.
That sum of the entire (a-b-c+d)*e that we did earlier

Comment: @VedantAthavale Please edit your question by adding an example of what you're trying to achieve and I'll try to help you. It is not clear for me like this :/